# Determining the non-trivial matrix $A$, where $ AB = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Example:
$A$ is a $3\times 4$ matrix.
$B$ is the following $4\times 2$ matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 \\
1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$A$ times $B$ equals a zero matrix.
How do I find the non-trivial solution to $A$?

Comment: You need only one nontrivial $A$?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: The mystery here is why on earth do the problem even ask for 3 row of A when it have no effects on the problem anyway. The asker might have forgotten some extra condition.

Comment: @Glna: Sometimes instructors are keen on misleading the students.

Comment: @John Yes, only one.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to note you have 2 vectors for the columns of $B$. Thus, if you pick 3 vectors orthogonal to the columns of $B$ (say, by finding 2 non-zero vectors orthogonal to the columns of $B$ via gram schmidt and the zero vector), then the matrix consisting of those 3 vectors as its rows satisfies this.

Note that mixing the rows (i.e. forming linear combinations of the prescribed rows) will give you another valid $A$.

(You should be thinking in terms of left null spaces).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I go about performing the part described in parentheses (step by step)?

Comment: One way is to write down the 2 equations for what you need for a vector to be orthogonal to the columns of $A$ and solve the 2 equations for their to get two non-zero rows. Then, add a zero row, and you have one solution. The rest of the solutions can be done by mixing the rows of this solution. Another way to find the 2 vectors orthogonal to the columns of $A$ is to start with them, augment them with the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ and apply gram-schmidt - the 2 non-zero vectors you get after gram schmidting the columns of $A$ are orthogonal to the columns of $A$.